# Show advanced custom field (ACF) if product content is empty

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created new ACF in Custom Fields panel and put this code in `/woocommerce/templates/single-product/tabs/description.php`:

```
...
<?php the_content(); ?>

//ACF code goes here:
<?php
$term = get_field('category');
if( $term ):
  echo 'Category: ' . '<a href="' . $get_site_url. '?product_cat=' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a>.';
endif;
?>
```

It works very good, but if content product is empty, ACF doesn't shown in description tab, i.e. there is no description tab.

How can I make ACF to be shown if product content is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Are you try pass the post ID ?
 like

```
$val= get_field( "test", $ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add space in product content.